# "Give someone an exact time" vs. "give someone the exact time"

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article

Can you please tell me if I need to use *a* or *the* in the context below?

> Can you give me **an** exact time you'll arrive.
>
> Can you give me **the** exact time you'll arrive.

I thought that *the* was the only correct article in the context, but I've heard native speakers use *a* as well.

Does a convey *a* slight difference in meaning there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the definite article **the**, the questioner is speaking of the arrival time as something that is already decided, which they want know.

With the indefinite article **an**, the questioner is thinking of arrival time as something to establish and agree to between the two of them.

In ordinary speech, it's a fine distinction, and either article could be used.